# Entry point in class file - More than 1 entry point

Tags: c#

What I am trying to do is create a project as I learn C# and have a new class in that project for each Euler problem.

So I have a base Program.cs file which has its entry point.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Euler
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

However I am defining my entry point in my own class correctly and have an error clearly showing I have more than one entry point.

How should I set my entry correctly?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Euler
{
    //Problem 1
    //If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
    //Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

    class Problem1
    {
        public Problem1(int args)
        {
            int num = 0;
            int limit = 1000;
            int sum = 0;
            while (num < limit)
            {
                if ((num % 3 ==0 )|| (num % 5 == 0))
                {
                    sum = sum + num;
                    num++;
                }
                else
                {
                    num++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
        }
    }


}
```

I know this is a newbie thing but it doesn't seem obvious.

```
Error   1   Program 'c:\Users\Sayth\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Euler\Euler\obj\Debug\Euler.exe' has more than one entry point defined: 'Euler.Program.Main(string[])'.  Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.    c:\users\sayth\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Euler\Euler\Program.cs 11  21  Euler
Error   2   Program 'c:\Users\Sayth\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Euler\Euler\obj\Debug\Euler.exe' has more than one entry point defined: 'Euler.Problem1.Main(string[])'.  Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.   c:\users\sayth\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Euler\Euler\Problem1.cs    15  21  Euler
```

**EDIT** I have  resolved the entry point errors, the code below doesn't work but for other reasons not related  to this question.

```
class Problem1
    {
        public int Sum53(int args)
        {
            int num = 0;
            int limit = 1000;
            int sum = 0;
            while (num < limit)
            {
                if ((num % 3 == 0) || (num % 5 == 0))
                {
                    sum = sum + num;
                    num++;
                }
                else
                {
                    num++;
                }
            }
            return sum;
        }

        public string myValue(string args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is the total :" + );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see only one entry point there. If you truly have multiples, make sure to set the startup object in your project settings.

Comment: Clearly not enough info to diagnose... I bet searching for "main" in your whole project would reveal the problem.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov        no that didn't help do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov     that's all the info available its a brand new project if I can create something to assist I am more than happy to.

Comment: your error snippet clearly says that you have a function called `Main` in the `Problem1.cs` class file, but you did not list that in your snippet here.

Comment: it's worth noting that the entry point `Main` is a special function that defines the **first** function that should run when a program starts.  You do not need an entry point in each class file, since you will only actually have one `.exe` and therefore only one function that can be run **first**.

Comment: Now I see no entry points. You have to provide one `static int Main()`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Main Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551412/multiple-main-functions)

Answer (score 2):

You only can have a single entry point in the program (unless you tell the compiler otherwise which one to use). But that entry point can call whatever you want. So if you wanted to have multiple different entry functions for experimenting with, you can simply uncomment the function you want to run.

```
static void Main(string[] args) //You can't have any other functions with this signature in your project
{
    Function1(args);
    //Function3(args);
    //Function2(args);
}

static void Function1(string[] args)
{
}

static void Function2(string[] args)
{
}

static void Function3(string[] args)
{
}
```

Comment: you *can* have multiple functions with the same `Main` signature, but if you do, you have to use compiler switches to indicate which one the framework should link to.  That is probably a bit above the basic level of the question, however...

Comment: @Claies Yes, I alluded to that compiler switch, but I didn't give an example as I've never used it before. Feel free to edit it into my question or post your own answer. It might be above the level of the question poster, but questions on Stack Overflow aren't only for the poster's benefit: they're for everyone else who comes along in the future with a similar question.