# why the main method is printing nothing in the sub class?

Tags: java

"mysecondclass" which is a sub class of the super class "myfirstclass" 
should inherit all the properties of the super class "myfirstclass"
and it's expected to output the value of x but instead it prints nothing

```
package myfirstproject;

public class myfirstclass {
    protected int x = 10;
    //getter 
    public void getX() {
     System.out.println(x);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
/* it asked me to define this main method here although it's useless in this situation 
   */
    }
}
class mysecondclass extends myfirstclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    mysecondclass mysecondobject = new mysecondclass();
    mysecondobject.getX(); //prints nothing 
    }
}
```

i am really newbie in java and i am actually still learning it's basics
also i do not know why it always asks me to add the main method in the super class although i have already declared one in the sub class (i heard one main method is enough for one java file)
any help is really appreciated , thanks in advance

Comment: How are you running this?

Comment: In Java, usually we only need one main method as entry in the public class which the class name is also file name. So you only need move your main method from sub class into parent class. You will be fine.

Comment: @yuanqingfei you can have main methods defined in any class you like, provided it's not an inner class (which neither of these classes are).

Comment: the main method in mysecondclass is static, so its not actually for overriding the (static) method in the first class. When you said "it always asks me to add the main method", who is it? Or what is it?

Comment: @AndyTurner  I know that, I said `ususally`, in his case, you can see that there is only one public class. That means it is the main class. And when you try to invoke main method, it will only find main method of main class. As for all the other class in this same java file, they are not useful.

Comment: @yuanqingfei but there's no need to "move your main method from sub class into parent class". That's not the problem. "That means it is the main class" There's no special thing called a "main class". The main *method* can be declared in any non-inner class.

Comment: @AndyTurner  obviously, he want make his main method(in the secondclass) running. What I offered is a workable solution for him.

Comment: @yuanqingfei if the main method has to be defined in `mysecondclass`, suggesting moving it into `myfirstclass` is not a solution (and even if OP is mistaken in "having to", referring to `mysecondclass` from `myfirstclass`'s main method would create a cyclical dependency). You simply have to run, e.g. with `java myfirstproject.mysecondclass`.

Comment: @AndyTurner  Have you tried? I tried in my local machine. It works. I don't met any cyclical dependency.

Comment: @yuanqingfei Java can compile and run classes with cyclical dependencies, but that doesn't mean it is a good idea to do it.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but Java convention is to use Pascal case for class names, meaning that convention dictates your classes should be `MyFirstClass` and `MySecondClass`. Adhering to conventions makes your code more readable. Code that is easy to read gets more and faster assistance.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551412/multiple-main-functions/11551423#11551423

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not understanding the function

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

In Java Docs :

> The public static void keywords mean the Java 1 virtual machine (JVM)
>   interpreter can call the program's main method to start the program
>   (public) without creating an instance of the class (static), and the
>   program does not return data to the Java VM interpreter (void) when it
>   ends.

You have two

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

In two different classes! You are running or compiling the one that uses `myfirstclass` So for this type of example or test is a good practice to have only one Java class Main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Call Your classes
    }
}
```

Be more clean and organized in your code!

And one other thing. For running by Command Line use this type of commands

```
java MyApp arg1 arg2
```

When in doubt always [read the Docs!](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways to make your code running as you wish

1) create 2 java file. one is myfirstclass.java the second is mysecondclass.java. each hold their main class. Thus you can kick off any main method as you wish.

2) just keep these 2 class in the same java file. then when you running it, it will only run the main method in default in the public class.

Comment: "it will only run the main method in default in the public class." Java doesn't require a main method to be in a public class, nor does it run any class by default. Java runs the class you tell it to run. If you invoke `java myproject.myfirstclass`, it runs the main method in that class; if you invoke `java myproject.mysecondclass`, it runs the main method in that class.

Comment: @AndyTurner  have you tried in Eclipse? if you don't define the main method in public class, you have no chance to run the main method in secondclass.  I agree with you if he is with command line.

Answer (score -2):

Just change the public keyword to the second class. If you are using an online compiler, they usually look for the main method inside the public class.

```
package myfirstproject;

 class myfirstclass {
    protected int x = 10;
    //getter 
    public void getX() {
     System.out.println(x);
    }

}
public class mysecondclass extends myfirstclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    mysecondclass mysecondobject = new mysecondclass();
    mysecondobject.getX(); //printx X
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Thus he need change his java file name.